# How do I multiply by a method in a different class java

Tags: java

I want to know how to call an income method that is located in a different method. Currently, my income method is located in a TaxPayer class. I want to call on this method however, and use it in the equation below income * corporate rate = tax. How do I do this?
Tax calculator:

```
`public class TaxCalculator {
double tax;



/**
 * Creates a TaxCalculator using 2021-2022 tax rates;
 */
public TaxCalculator() {

}

/**
 * Calculates a tax payer's tax assuming they are a corporation.
 * 
 * @precondition payer != null AND payer.isCorporation()==true
 * @postcondition none
 * 
 * @param payer the tax payer
 */

public double corporaterate = 0.21;
public double taxcalc(TaxPayer income) {
    tax = income.getIncome() * corporaterate;
    return tax;
}


public double calculateCorporateIncomeTax(TaxPayer payer) {
    if (tax < 0) {
        tax = 0;
    }
    
    return tax;
}`
```

I am trying to call upon my method located in a different class called Tax Payer:

```
public class TaxPayer {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private boolean isCorporation;
    private double income;
    
    /**
     * Creates a new taxpayer.
     * 
     * @precondition name != null AND !name.isEmpty() AND age >= 0
     * @postcondition getName()==name AND getAge()==age AND getIsBusiness()=isBusiness
     * 
     * @param name the person or business' name
     * @param age the person's age (ignored if it is a business)
     * @param income the annual income
     * @param isCorporation true if the taxpayer is a business, false otherwise
     */
    public TaxPayer(String name, int age, double income, boolean isCorporation) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.isCorporation = isCorporation;
        this.income = income;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the name
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the age
     * @return the age
     */
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
    
    /**
     * Gets the taxpayer's annual income.
     * @return the taxpayer's annual income.
     */
    public double getIncome() {
        return this.income;
    }

    /**
     * Gets whether or not this is a corporation (and not a person)
     * @return true if a corporation, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isCorporation() {
        return this.isCorporation;
    }
    
    
}
```

I want to know how to call this getIncome method.

Comment: This is what I have so far. It works when the input is 0 and when the input is less then 0 however, it doesn't work when the input is above 0. I just want to know how to basically do input * the corporate rate = tax (double)

Comment: Remember, [put all your details in the post](/help/how-to-ask), just use the [edit] function and work them into your post, don't post comments with additional details. (and don't just write "edit:" and then the new details, actually work them into your post, so that they're in the right place in the text relevant to what you're talking about)

Comment: Your question does not make clear where exactly is the problem you are facing. Making a guess, are you perhaps trying to do `tax = income.getIncome() * corporaterate`?

Comment: @Chaosfire I apologize for not being clearer. I am just trying to figure out how to multiply the income method by the corporaterate when the income method is in a different class. I can't figure out how to call the method when it is in another class. Currently it is in another class called Tax Payer.

Comment: @JOHN As mentioned in another comment, you should edit your question with such information, not adding comments, there is even link for editing included. About how to call the method, it's done exactly the way i wrote it in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

To call method getIncome() that is a method of class TaxPayer, there are two possibilities, depending upon whether the method is a static method or an instance method.

For a static method, from the other class (such as from TaxCalculator):

```
tax = TaxPayer.getIncome() * corporateRate;  // TaxPayer is a class; getIncome() is a static method
```

For instance methods, you need an instance of a TaxPayer object:

```
tax = taxPayer.getIncome() * corporateRate;  // taxPayer is an object of type TaxPayer; getIncome is an instance method
```

From what you posted, it appears that you're working with an instance method, and the calculate method that calls the getIncome() method gets an instance of TaxPayer as it's parameter. If this is all true, the code seems correct. Before you call calculateCorporateIncomeTax(payer), you should verify that TaxPayer object *payer* is initialized correctly.

As others have stated, it would be easier to answer with full code posted.

Comment: I appreciate your answer! Thank you so much. I have updated my code and shown the entirety of the TaxPayer class.